# My bukkit plugin doesn't work

Tags: java, json, minecraft, bukkit

My Bukkit plugin does't Work!

Server Output:

```
>     [17:49:00] [Server thread/INFO]: [ChatManager1] Enabling ChatManager1 v0.1
>     [17:49:00] [Server thread/ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling ChatManager1 v0.1 (Is it up to date?)
>     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin already initialized!
>       at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.initialize(PluginClassLoader.java:98)
> ~[src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>       at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.<init>(JavaPlugin.java:66) ~[src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>       at me.whispereq.colorCodes.Main.<init>(Main.java:9) ~[?:?]
>       at me.whispereq.colorCodes.Main.onEnable(Main.java:12) ~[?:?]
>       at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:316)
> ~[src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>       at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:324)
> [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>       at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:404)
> [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>       at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R4.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:455)
> [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>       at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R4.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:389)
> [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>       at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.n(MinecraftServer.java:352)
> [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>       at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.g(MinecraftServer.java:326)
> [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>       at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:282)
> [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>       at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:189)
> [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>       at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:436)
> [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>       at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:628)
> [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Initial initialization
>       at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.initialize(PluginClassLoader.java:101)
> ~[src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>       at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.<init>(JavaPlugin.java:66) ~[src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>       at me.whispereq.colorCodes.Main.<init>(Main.java:9) ~[?:?]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
>       at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:52)
> ~[src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>       at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:127)
> ~[src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>       at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:328)
> ~[src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>       at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:251)
> ~[src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>       at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R4.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:364)
> ~[src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>       at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R4.CraftServer.<init>(CraftServer.java:326)
> ~[src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>       at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PlayerList.<init>(PlayerList.java:68)
> ~[src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>       at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.DedicatedPlayerList.<init>(SourceFile:14)
> ~[src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>       at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:133)
> ~[src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
>       ... 2 more
>     [17:49:00
```

I have 2 Classes the first is Main and the Second is Config
this is code from Main class:

```
package me.whispereq.colorCodes;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements CommandExecutor{
    public static Main instance;
    public static void s(String mg){
        System.out.println(mg);
    }
    public void onEnable(){
        instance = this;
        s("=======================================");
        s("         CHAT MANAGER MAIN");
        s("Loading Plugin chat manager by the whispereq");
        s("=======================================");
        getCommand("helpchat").setExecutor(new Config());
        saveDefaultConfig();
    }
    public static Main getInst(){
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Code from Config Class:

```
package me.whispereq.colorCodes;
import java.util.List;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.event.player.AsyncPlayerChatEvent;

public class Config implements CommandExecutor {
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender s, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if ((cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("helpchat")) && (args.length == 0)){
            s.sendMessage("§6-----------------------------");
            s.sendMessage("§cCommands:");
            s.sendMessage(" §7/help");
            s.sendMessage("§cFunctions");
            s.sendMessage(" §7Swear words replacement, blankfields");
            s.sendMessage(" §7Color codes, swear repl character,");
            s.sendMessage(" §cPlugin Includes COnfig File!");
            s.sendMessage("§6-----------------------------");
        }
        else if (args.length > 0){
            s.sendMessage("§4/help");
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static void onChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e){
        List<?> swear = Main.getInst().getConfig().getList("swearwords");
        String replacement = Main.getInst().getConfig().getString("sword-char");
        String warn = Main.getInst().getConfig().getString("sword-msg");
        List<?> blanks = Main.getInst().getConfig().getList("blankfields");
        String bfmsg = Main.getInst().getConfig().getString("use-msg");
        List<?> colors = Main.getInst().getConfig().getList("colorcodes");
        String cuse = Main.getInst().getConfig().getString("coloruse");
        if (e.getMessage().contains((CharSequence) swear)){
            e.getMessage().replace((CharSequence) swear, replacement);
            e.getPlayer().sendMessage(warn + Bukkit.getServerName());
        }
        else if (e.getMessage().contains((CharSequence) blanks)){
            e.getMessage().replace((CharSequence) blanks, "");
            e.getPlayer().sendMessage(bfmsg);
        }
        else if (e.getMessage().contains((CharSequence) colors)){
            e.getMessage().replace((CharSequence) colors, "§");
            e.getPlayer().sendMessage(cuse);
        }
    }
}
```

Config.yml file:

```
###########################
#     Color Codes List    #
###########################
# Character, word #
colorcodes:
  - '&'

coloruse: §6You have used§4§l ColorCodes§6.
###########################
#       BLANK FIELDS      #
###########################
# Character, word #
blankfields:
  - '<BlankField>'

use-msg: §6You have used an §c§lBlank Field§6 in yours Sentence.
###########################
#       SWEARING          #
###########################
# String, word, character, sentence, integer #
swearwords:
  - '...'

sword-char: xxxx
#WARN! after message will be inerted server Name from #
# server.properties file! #
sword-msg: §c§lHey!§7 Please dont Spam on 
#----------------------------------------#
# BLankfields are replaced on the chat when
# message sent by an blank String ''
#----------------------------------------#
# Color codes are the replacements of
# Characters '§' in minecraft chat
# Color codes makes possible to write
# messages in multiple Colors!
#-----------------------------------------#
# Maybe you dont like, that a player swears
# on yours serwer, and beacuse of it
# there was added this category.
#--- ADDING AN SWEAR WORD ---#
# To add an swear word make 1 TAB in a new
# line write '-' char make space after it
# write 2 aposthrops ' and between
# it write new swear word.
# it should look like this:
#
#swearwords:
# - 'my swear word'
#
#-----------------------------------------#
# swear word repalcement: char, word,
# sentence, or other things, with it will
# be replaced the serar word.
# INFO: you can make a swear word an
# BLANK FIELD.
#-----------------------------------------#
```

and that's the Plugin.yml File:

```
name: ChatManager1
version: 0.1
main: me.whispereq.colorCodes.Main
description: Chat Management with Config
author: whispereq
commands:
  help:
    description: Plugin informations
```

Please help me, this is a big project, and I have no idea why it doesn't work. Thanks all!
~whispereq

NEW:
I removed all other plugins and i became this code / Server Log:

```
[18:28:43] [Server thread/INFO]: [ChatManager1] Enabling ChatManager1 v0.1
[18:28:43] [Server thread/INFO]: =======================================
[18:28:43] [Server thread/INFO]:          CHAT MANAGER MAIN
[18:28:43] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading Plugin chat manager by the whispereq
[18:28:43] [Server thread/INFO]: =======================================
[18:28:43] [Server thread/ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling ChatManager1 v0.1 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at me.whispereq.colorCodes.Main.onEnable(Main.java:15) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:316) ~[src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:324) [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:404) [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R4.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:455) [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R4.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:389) [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.n(MinecraftServer.java:352) [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.g(MinecraftServer.java:326) [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:282) [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:189) [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:436) [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:628) [src.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-20-g0b2ed13-b3108jnks]
[18:28:43] [Server thread/INFO]: Server
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have two jars or two of the same plugins with the same package names in the same plugin folder?

Comment: YEs i am sure andrew, but i removed all other plugins, and i get an other Error, yuo see it in the Ask i added it [Edited]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First error indicated, that there are 2 or more plugins with the same path to the main class (same package + same class name) - Bukkit needs those main class paths to be unique.

Second error - the command was not added in the plugin.yml file, so getCommand() method was throwing the NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

The first error usually indicates that there is more than one plugin with the same name.

The second error points to line 15 in your `Main.class`. The `NullPointerException` indicates that some object you are using is `null`.

Be sure that you checked every object you are referencing and make sure they're not null.